# Zipkin with elasticsearch storage (QueryParsingException)

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-cloud, zipkin

I have a question regarding Zipkin with elasticsearch storage.

After updating spring-cloud-sleuth to `1.1.1.RELEASE`(because we updated spring boot from 1.3.8 to 1.4.4 and spring cloud from Brixton.SR6 to Camden.SR4) we also updated `zipkin-storage-elasticsearch` and `zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-elasticsearch` to version `1.16.2` in the pom.xml of our zipkin service. We are using elasticsearch version `2.4.1`.
When we boot up the service we get an 
[error on zipkin's ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMSiw.png) and a stacktrace:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[cAMggVueTv67tHV7aykwlg][zipkin-2017-03-29][0]: RemoteTransportException[[Infamnia][172.18.0.20:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"should":[{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"annotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"annotations"}},{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"binaryAnnotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"binaryAnnotations"}}]}}}},"aggregations":{"name_agg":{"terms":{"field":"name","size":2147483647,"order":{"_term":"asc"}}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[nested] nested object under path [annotations] is not of nested type]; }{[cAMggVueTv67tHV7aykwlg][zipkin-2017-03-29][1]: RemoteTransportException[[Infamnia][172.18.0.20:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"should":[{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"annotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"annotations"}},{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"binaryAnnotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"binaryAnnotations"}}]}}}},"aggregations":{"name_agg":{"terms":{"field":"name","size":2147483647,"order":{"_term":"asc"}}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[nested] nested object under path [annotations] is not of nested type]; }{[cAMggVueTv67tHV7aykwlg][zipkin-2017-03-29][2]: RemoteTransportException[[Infamnia][172.18.0.20:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"should":[{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"annotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"annotations"}},{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"binaryAnnotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"binaryAnnotations"}}]}}}},"aggregations":{"name_agg":{"terms":{"field":"name","size":2147483647,"order":{"_term":"asc"}}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[nested] nested object under path [annotations] is not of nested type]; }{[cAMggVueTv67tHV7aykwlg][zipkin-2017-03-29][3]: RemoteTransportException[[Infamnia][172.18.0.20:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"should":[{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"annotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"annotations"}},{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"binaryAnnotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"binaryAnnotations"}}]}}}},"aggregations":{"name_agg":{"terms":{"field":"name","size":2147483647,"order":{"_term":"asc"}}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[nested] nested object under path [annotations] is not of nested type]; }{[cAMggVueTv67tHV7aykwlg][zipkin-2017-03-29][4]: RemoteTransportException[[Infamnia][172.18.0.20:9300][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[failed to parse search source [{"size":0,"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"should":[{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"annotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"annotations"}},{"nested":{"query":{"term":{"binaryAnnotations.endpoint.serviceName":"xxx"}},"path":"binaryAnnotations"}}]}}}},"aggregations":{"name_agg":{"terms":{"field":"name","size":2147483647,"order":{"_term":"asc"}}}}}]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[nested] nested object under path [annotations] is not of nested type]; }] with root cause    


org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParsingException: [nested] nested object under path [annotations] is not of nested type
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.support.NestedInnerQueryParseSupport.setPath(NestedInnerQueryParseSupport.java:162)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.NestedQueryParser.parse(NestedQueryParser.java:82)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryParser.parse(BoolQueryParser.java:120)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerFilter(QueryParseContext.java:263)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.BoolQueryParser.parse(BoolQueryParser.java:91)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryParseContext.parseInnerQuery(QueryParseContext.java:250)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.innerParse(IndexQueryParserService.java:320)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:223)
at org.elasticsearch.index.query.IndexQueryParserService.parse(IndexQueryParserService.java:218)
at org.elasticsearch.search.query.QueryParseElement.parse(QueryParseElement.java:33)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.parseSource(SearchService.java:856)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createContext(SearchService.java:667)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.createAndPutContext(SearchService.java:633)
at org.elasticsearch.search.SearchService.executeQueryPhase(SearchService.java:377)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:368)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$SearchQueryTransportHandler.messageReceived(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:365)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportRequestHandler.messageReceived(TransportRequestHandler.java:33)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Zipkin was working with spring-cloud-sleuth `1.0.0.RELEASE`, zipkin-storage-elasticsearch, zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-elasticsearch `1.7.0` and elasticsearch `2.3.5`. What am I missing here? Which versions should work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is better to use the zipkin's http variant of Elasticsearch as it cannot conflict with Spring Boot's elasticsearch library versions.

I would set everything in zipkin's group id to latest (currently 1.21.0 which is Spring Boot 1.4.x) and use zipkin-autoconfigure-storage-elasticsearch-http (plus.. the one you are using [will be dropped](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/issues/1511))

Make sure your es hosts is specified in url syntax ex. http://host1:9200